# C++ ordered map optimized with index access

Tags: c++, templates, data-structures, stl, containers

In short, my question is, **how to maximize the performance of ordered map (e.g. implemented as `std::map`) with good support of index access?**

Details:

We can of course use some code like `std::advance(it, index)` to achieve index access where `it` is an iterator of `std::map`. However, the performance becomes a severe issue when `std::map` is large, so traversing the `std::map` is very slow.

I hope the container `map` can support these:

- **Basic Operations.** Just behave like a normal `std::map`. For example, insertion, deletion, access values by keys. Complexity lower than `O(N)` is expected.
- **Orderliness.** We can access the **`i`-th smallest (by keys) item** by index access. Indices are not totally random, they are a bit similar (so my first thought is to use something like cache, but I have no idea). We may alter the `map` by insertion or deletion, so saving previously accessed iterators may not be fully feasible because they may point to wrong positions after modification to `map`.

What is the proper data structure or implementation to achieve this goal? Thank you!

Goal:

A good implementation of **ordered map** with good support of **index access** (perhaps with caching)? It is okay not to be fully stored in a sorted order for all items.

Comment: This feels like you're asking us to do your C++ basics class homework.

Comment: Do you only need indexed access or do you still need to access by key as well? What other requirements do you have? Do you need fast insertion and removal? Could you just use a sorted vector?

Comment: No, it is not my homework, though the problem might be silly to you. I encountered the problem when I use `std::advance(it, index)` for indexing a `std::map`. I profile my code and find out most of the time was spent on this line of code.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Basic operations of `std::map` like insertion, deletion, access by keys are expected. It would be good to have index access support.

Comment: Using some variant a balanced tree where additionally each node knows the size of its subtree would get you both logarithmic search by key and index.

Comment: Not sure if flat_map (in Boost; later in std) is what you need. It is basically an ordered vector. I think it supports (or could support) random access iterators. Insertions and deletions may take longer though when many elements needs to be moved.

Comment: A sorted vector might still offer the best performance for a surprisingly large number of elements, you'll need to benchmark it

Comment: the index is the key. You dont need `advance` but you can use `operator[]`

Comment: If you care about 'i-th smallest' and i is not a very small number, you probably want a sorted vector like already stated above.

Comment: It seems that you are looking for what is called [_order statistic trees_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree); relevant questions: [Fast, sorted data structure with random access?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14173717/580083), [Order Statistic Tree in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11230734/580083). Available implementation: https://github.com/dkondor/orbtree.

Comment: @DanielLangr Great! This seems to be what I am looking for!