# Using custom allocator to make std::list cache friendly?

Tags: c++, allocator

During my daily work, I am always advised by senior member of the team that list is not cache friendly so I should `vector`. I understand that `list` is not continuous so that the memory allocation is scattered around the whole memory.

However, very often I do need the functionality of a `list` (or a `map`). So I am wondering if I can write my own allocator, which is a `vector` underneath. Every time when I `push_back`, my own allocator will allocate a new item from a per-allocated `vector`.

When I travel the `list`/`map`, the cache locality is preserved.

Does this make sense to any of you?

Comment: `std::list` isn't an associative container.

Comment: What your looking for is called a stack allocator

Comment: Obvious question: why not just use a `vector`? What does this construction give you that a `vector` doesn't? If you try to use any of the functionality that's ordinarily more efficient on a `list` than a `vector`, you'll leak memory.

Comment: I have a roughly fixed size list, i constantly need to insert/erase in the middle of it, i don't think this can be easily replaced by a vector

Comment: @user2357112 This can be done without leaking memory if the list can see the elements in a different order than the vector sees the list nodes.

Comment: The value add of `list` over `vector` is O(1) insert and remove. I can't think of a way to get this and guarantee decent spatial locality.

Comment: Do some benchmarks.  For 500,000 elements vector out performed list (and map) doing random insert deletes.

Comment: See the video linked in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24542936/vector-vs-map-performance-confusion

Comment: I think the main reason you'd use `std::list` over `std::vector` is that removing from the middle of `std::list` doesn't invalidate iterators. If you don't need that property of lists then I'd suggest using a vector instead.

Comment: with so many comments, why nobody gives a proper answer?

Comment: @user152503 your collection can't have insert and remove *and* be fixed length; if an element is added or removed, the collection grows or shrinks.  If you reserve an appropriate sized array, you *can* do it so that it's a cache friendly `list`-like, but the details of arranging and finding the elements depend strongly on which operations you want to optimize.  That said, your seniors need to wait until the product is profiled, or you will end up spending unnecessary time and effort deciding and refining those details.  Unless you really have a boat, don't re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[std::list](http://cs.brown.edu/~jwicks/libstdc++/html_user/stl__list_8h-source.html) and std::set (I believe you need set as alternative to list, not a map) both will use allocator for there internals. 
You can preallocating a block of memory and use it to create your objects and containers. If you google, you will find several. In this case your objects instead if "scattered around the whole memory" will be scattered around your block of memory. If block fit on the cache, you will get some improvement. But it will not completely solve you problem.

From description of the problem, you really need **[deque](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/)**. Deque is implemented as a list of arrays. It is compromise between vector and a list. It is cache friendly for iteration and faster then array when you insert.

So you can choose either custom allocator or deque, depends on your collection size.

[image]