# Order Statistic Tree in C++ with duplicates

Tags: c++, data-structures

Is there a way to support duplicates for the Order statistic tree in C++? I have found a way to construct an order statistic set [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11230734/order-statistic-tree-in-c). But it does not support duplicate keys.

For example, if I have `s = {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4}`. I want `s.find_by_order(0) == s.find_by_order(1) == 1`. It seems that if we can use the value of each key as the count and store the total counts in all subtrees in the node, we can achieve that goal. But I don't know how to do that with `__gnu_pbds`. Is there a simpler modification of the tree to support that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may implement a multiset in terms of a set of pairs. In each pair, the first element represents the value, while the second element denotes its unique insertion order (or a timestamp). This way, we can logically store duplicate values while keeping the key representations unique.

Below is a simple example:

```cpp
#include <iostream> 
#include <ext/pb_ds/assoc_container.hpp> 
#include <ext/pb_ds/tree_policy.hpp> 

using namespace std; 
using namespace __gnu_pbds; 

struct ost_multiset {
    typedef pair<int, unsigned> pii;
    typedef tree<
        pii,
        null_type,
        less<pii>,
        rb_tree_tag,
        tree_order_statistics_node_update
    > ost;

    ost s;
    unsigned cnt = 0;

    ost_multiset() = default;
    ost_multiset(initializer_list<int> l) {
        for (int x : l) {
            insert(x);
        }
    }
    void insert(int x) {
        s.insert({x, cnt++});
    }
    ost::iterator find_by_order(int k) {
        return s.find_by_order(k);
    }
    // erase all elements with value x
    void erase(int x) {
        auto it = s.lower_bound({x, 0});
        while (it != s.end() && it->first == x) {
            erase(it++);
        }
    }
    // erase a single element
    void erase(ost::iterator it) {
        s.erase(it);
    }

    size_t size() const {
        return s.size();
    }
};

int main() {
    ost_multiset s {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4};
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i) {
        cout << s.find_by_order(i)->first << ",\n"[i == s.size() - 1];
    }
    // the above loop prints 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4
    
    s.erase(1);
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i) {
        cout << s.find_by_order(i)->first << ",\n"[i == s.size() - 1];
    }
    // the above loop prints 2, 2, 3, 4

    s.erase(s.find_by_order(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i) {
        cout << s.find_by_order(i)->first << ",\n"[i == s.size() - 1];
    }
    // the above loop prints 2, 3, 4
}
```